# Density and overlapping in tikz chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I got the following code right now for my chart:

```
\begin{figure}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}
 \fbox{

 \vspace*{-100pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\scalefont{1}}]
  \centering
  \begin{axis} [

  height=0.9\textheight, width=0.9\textwidth,

xbar, xmin=0,
tick align=inside,
tickwidth = 0pt, 
symbolic y coords={%

{Others},
{Test cases},
{Error reports},
{Screenshots},
{Stack traces},
{Steps to reproduce},
{Expected behavior},
{Observed behavior},
{Summary},
{Hardware,...},
{Severity},

{Version}, {Product/App name}},

  ytick=data,
  nodes near coords,
  nodes near coords align={horizontal},
  xlabel={Percentage of votes},
  ]


  \addplot +[area legend] coordinates {
    (33.33,{Product/App name}) 
    (58.33,{Version}) 
    (8.33,{Severity}) 
    (50,{Hardware,...})
    (25,{Summary}) 
    (58.33,{Observed behavior}) 
    (25,{Expected behavior}) 
    (75,{Steps to reproduce})
    (58.33,{Stack traces}) 
    (25,{Screenshots}) 
    (25,{Error reports}) 
    (0,{Test cases})};

\addplot +[area legend] coordinates {
    (30.95,{Product/App name}) 
    (61.90,{Version}) 
    (26.19,{Severity}) 
    (69.05,{Hardware,...})
    (21.43,{Summary}) 
    (59.52,{Observed behavior}) 
    (28.57,{Expected behavior}) 
    (88.10,{Steps to reproduce})
    (45.24,{Stack traces}) 
    (30.95,{Screenshots}) 
    (33.33,{Error reports}) 
    (14.29,{Test cases})};
    
    legend cell align = left,
    \legend{Desktop, Mobile }
  \end{axis}

  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption{Comparison of important information}
  \label{fig:importantcriteria}
  \end{figure}
```

Which creates this bar chart

[image]

The problem is for one the overlapping 88.1 value and I would also like to make the bars little closer to each other so I can save some space. Also the space between the last bars and the x a

Tried to play around with `enlargelimits` but this created a margin on all sides, but I would prefer the bars starting right from the axis on the left side (at least I think that looks better).

Comment: Please post a full MWE not just a code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid having the bars separated from each other by changing `xbar`'s optional argument and the spacing between each group of bars is set by the overall height of the graph as PGFplots spreads them all out. Also, you can enlarge the upper *x* limits by using `enlarge x limits=upper`.  I further adjust it by setting the value to `0.15` which seems an appropriate amount for this plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[
      height=13cm,
      width=10cm,
      xbar=0pt,
      bar width=1em,
      xmin=0,
      xlabel={Percentage of votes},
      ytick=data,
      enlarge x limits={upper,value=0.15},
      tick align=inside,
      tickwidth = 0pt, 
      symbolic y coords={%
        {Others},
        {Test cases},
        {Error reports},
        {Screenshots},
        {Stack traces},
        {Steps to reproduce},
        {Expected behavior},
        {Observed behavior},
        {Summary},
        {Hardware,...},
        {Severity},
        {Version}, 
        {Product/App name}
      },
      nodes near coords,
      nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]

    \addplot +[area legend] coordinates { 
      (33.33,{Product/App name})
      (58.33,{Version}) 
      (8.33,{Severity}) 
      (50,{Hardware,...})  
      (25,{Summary})
      (58.33,{Observed behavior}) 
      (25,{Expected behavior}) 
      (75,{Steps to reproduce}) 
      (58.33,{Stack traces}) 
      (25,{Screenshots}) 
      (25,{Error reports}) 
      (0,{Test cases})};

    \addplot +[area legend] coordinates {
      (30.95,{Product/App name})
      (61.90,{Version}) 
      (26.19,{Severity}) 
      (69.05,{Hardware,...})
      (21.43,{Summary}) 
      (59.52,{Observed behavior}) 
      (28.57,{Expected behavior})
      (88.10,{Steps to reproduce}) 
      (45.24,{Stack traces}) 
      (30.95,{Screenshots})
      (33.33,{Error reports}) 
      (14.29,{Test cases})
    };

    % legend cell align = left, \legend{Desktop, Mobile }
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note, I did not include the legend because you seem to have missed part of the code of it in your MWE.

Comment: Thank you! These parameters pretty much help and solve this problem.